# Copy Constructor for unsorted list in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm trying to create a copy constructor for an unsorted list. Below is my code:

```
UnsortedType::UnsortedType(const UnsortedType &s)
{
    length = s.length;
    if (s.listData == NULL)
    {
        listData = NULL;
        return;
    }
    listData = new NodeType;
    NodeType *temp1 = listData, *temp2 = s.listData;
    while (temp2 != NULL)
    {
        temp1->info = temp2->info;
        temp2 = temp2->next;
        temp1->next = new NodeType;
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }
    temp1 = NULL;
}
```

I have no clue why but for the last node is not set to NULL. This causes problems when calling the destructor. The destructor deletes nodes until it finds a node set to NULL. Since no node is set to NULL, it keeps deleting until encountering a run time error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why does your code have no documenting comments? Also I don't think your algorithm is right. You're not actually copying anything other than the structure, surely?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think it would be that complex to other people here but your probably right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is if temp2 is null in statement:

```
temp2 = temp2->next;
```

then you are unnecessary allocating memory for

```
temp1->next = new NodeType;
```

and then at the end setting temp1 to NULL in statement:

```
temp1 = NULL;
```

The ideal code should be:

```
    while (1)
    {
        temp1->info = temp2->info;
        temp2 = temp2->next;
        if (temp2 != NULL) //Where temp2 is copyable
        {
             temp1->next = new NodeType;
             temp1 = temp1->next;
        }
        else
        {
             temp1->next = NULL;
             break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for solving it AND explaining the problem. I didn't realize that I couldn't change it from "new NodeType" to NULL.

One Question: What if I added
delete temp;
temp = NULL;

would that have worked?

Comment: No it will not work. You should able to point the NULL to the previous node. By deleting the current node and assigning it to NULL will not work. Please study singly linked list to get more clarity.

Comment: You _can_ change it from "new NodeType" to NULL. However, not only is that a memory leak but it is pointless as my answer explains.

Answer (score -1):

You set `temp1` to `NULL`; that's just a local variable. It's a useless thing to do.

I'm not clear on how your data structure works, but presumably you meant to set the last `temp1->next` to `NULL`.